# How will Mathematics courses help learning Computability Theory and Complexity Theory?

Tags: computer-science, education, computational-complexity, computability

I'm a senior undergraduate Mathematics student, and I'm about to be a grad Mathematics student in M.Sc. course. Yet I aim to be a Ph.D. in CS.

The reason for this bizarre route is because I'm fascinated by **Computability Theory** and **Complexity Theory**. I regard them as branches of pure mathematics, so I decided to have a strong mathematical background.

Yet I don't know how Mathematics courses will help learning Computability Theory and Complexity Theory. Here, I focus on the following courses, which are mandatory:

- **Algebra 1**: Groups, rings, fields, vector spaces.
- **Real Analysis 1**: Lebesgue measure, Lebesgue integration.
- **Topology 1**: Homotopy, fundamental group, Van Kempen's theorem, covering space, group action.
- **Probability Theory 1**: Law of large numbers, martingale theory, ergodic theory.
- **Applied Mathematics 1**: Functionals, Green's function, Fourier transformation.
- **Complex Analysis**: Poisson integral, Schwarz lemma, Phragmén-Lindelöf principle, Runge's theorem, Mittag-Leffler theorem, Riemann mapping theorem.
- **Geometry 1**: Curves, surfaces, shape operator, Riemann geometry.

The list of all courses is shown [here.](http://math.korea.ac.kr/math/grad/normal.do)

Just in case, I state that I took almost all undergraduate math courses, including all "standard" ones. The followings are the courses I **couldn't** take:

> Algebraic Topology, Topological Data Analysis, Real Analysis (which differs from elementary Analysis), Insurance Mathematics, Financial Mathematics, Industrial Mathematics, Derivative (as in finance) Theory, Practical Data Analysis.

(And sorry if this question is off-topic here. Maybe CS SE or Academia SE is a better place.)

Comment: @WillJagy Are you serious? A huge chunk of modern computability theory is its interactions with algebra and analysis (e.g. via reverse mathematics), tools from probability theory are used all over the place in complexity theory, and being generally mathematically well-rounded is always a good thing on its own. I would never advise someone to avoid taking mathematics classes who's pursuing a degree related to mathematics.

Comment: @WillJagy OP's question "how will these courses help with field X?" might be read as "confirm that I don't need to learn these courses," but I would rather give them the benefit of the doubt and assume their intent was "in what ways would these courses help with field X?"

Comment: @angryavian got my point. I'm not *doubting* that they will help. I'm *sure* they will help.

Comment: As a TCS PhD student who did a bachelor in mathematics myself, what helped me most is the general skill of forming and understanding mathematical arguments. It didn't matter that much in what domain. In particular, I learned to do mathematics in a real analysis course (which was pretty much designed to be a "trial by fire"), and this could be the most valuable course I've had. Not because of the topic, I almost never use real analysis in my research field. It's because the course was a serious test of mathematical proving skills, and these skills generalize to mathematics as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rise of Computability Theory arguably began (under the name "Recursion Theory") as central concept in the statement and proof of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems in 1930ies, well before Turing.

In order to prove (essential) undecidability, Logician Tarski employed "computable reductions" in the 1940ies; which Cook in 1971 refined to polynomial-time reduction defining the complexity class NP.

Geometric Complexity Theory is currently counted among the most promising approaches to settle the P/NP Millennium Problem by quantitatively refining known qualitative results in Algebraic Geometry.

Generally speaking, breakthroughs (like Wiles' proof of Fermat's Last Theorem) often  arise from exhibiting surprising new connections between/to Mathematical fields.

Comment: Thanks, professor!